# Plotting a coastline on cartesian grid in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making maps of meteorological data (x,y-coordinates in m) using matplotlib.pyplot.contourf(). I want to plot a coastline, but all the examples I find on internet use lat-lon data (with cartopy or basemap).
Is there a way (without transforming the data to a lat-lon grid) to plot a coastline on my cartesian grid? I know size of the grid, and its center's lat-lon coordinates.

I haven't tried anything but look for similar examples, which I could not find.

Comment: please provide a minimal working example and show what you have so far!
... what is the projection of your "cartesian" data?

Comment: I found the solution, my data turned out to be on a gnomonic projection, which is supported by cartopy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use cartopy's gnomonic projection: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/crs/projections.html#gnomonic , e.g.
`proj =ccrs.Gnomonic(central_latitude=0, central_longitude= 0)`
The origin of the data need to be specified (in lat-lon), and it expects the data coordinates to be distance in meters from that origin. Then, the normal cartopy features (like coastlines) work as usual.